# How to set predefined macros in Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, g++, codeblocks, predefined-macro

Is there a way to set some predefined Macros for my local installation of Code::Blocks.

To elaborate on that, basically I would like to have certain blocks compiled only at pc and not anyplace I send the code to. One way to achieve this is as follows:

```
#define MYPC
#ifdef MYPC
 //do something
#else
 // do something else
#endif
```

I was to achieve the same thing, but I don't want to include the line #define MYPC and woud like to add this somewhere in the IDE. I know how to do this in Visual Studio, and I think it also exists in Code::Blocks as well.
Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Project - Properties - Project's build options - Compiler Settings - #defines.

Edit. Example of #defines edit box:

```
CONSTANT1
CONSTANT2="0"
```

Gives the following command line:

g++ -DCONSTANT1 -DCONSTANT2="0" ...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do I just write each #defines per line?

Comment: Yes, every constant must start from new line.

Comment: I have successfully defined macros in Project options and compiled ok, but in the editor of code blocks, it does not highlight correctly.

Comment: @SswaterShi Hmm, it looks like the editor won't parse the build specific `#defines` readily. It is still a missing feature in CB(almost after 6 years you posted the above comment).