# Codeblocks not recognizing tcl library

Tags: c, tcl, codeblocks

I am attempting to run an old program that uses tcl as well as legacy opengl. I managed to link the opengl libraries successfully; however, I cannot seem to get the tcl linker to work. For context, the program I am using came with include and lib folder. The lib folder contains `tclstub86_32.lib`, `tclstub86_64.lib`, and `tkstub86.lib` as well as opengl .libs. The include folder contains two folders: tcl_include and tk_include, which obviously contain all the .c and .h files for tcl and tk. The following pictures show my settings from using project -> build options:
[image]

[image]

[image]

The error I receive when compiling is:

```
C:\Users\amlut\Downloads\C\tkogl\curve.c|18|undefined reference to `_imp__Tcl_Free'|
```

And here is the bit of code that is throwing the error:

```
if (*line != NULL) Tcl_Free((char*)*line);
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the code is apparently linking against the Tcl stub library (an ABI/API adaptor library) but isn't compiling to use that library but rather to use a full Tcl library instead. When building an extension package, using the stub library is a good thing as it means that the resulting code is not bound to an exact version of the Tcl (and Tk) library but rather to a version of the Tcl ABI which has a much longer support cycle.

The fix is to define the `USE_TCL_STUBS` and `USE_TK_STUBS` (that has the identical issue; you have just hit the Tcl version of it first) C *preprocessor symbols* when building; set them both to `1` and recompile. This is [done under the Compiler Settings tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067246/how-to-set-predefined-macros-in-codeblocks) in Code::Blocks apparently.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, it appears even with `#defines` specified, it still throws the compiler error.  Are there any other avenues I should pursue?

Comment: Update: I added the `#defines` directly to the `tcl.h` header, and while the error went away, I get another error that states "No such file or directory".

Comment: Editing the `tcl.h` header file is _not_ the way to do this!

Comment: BTW, I don't actually understand the state of your system any more, but if you're doing things like editing header files provided by others, any answers that fully fix things for you are _extremely_ unlikely to apply to anyone else.

Comment: That was the only time I edited a header file, I deleted that one line to make it normal again. Though, it runs into the same error of not being able to identify any TCL/TK functions.

Comment: Assuming all the proper header files are intact, are there any other avenues I could explore to solve this issue?